# Dividing my cardview design issue

Tags: android

I am developing an app which i have to divide the cardview to 2 parts.

I have done this :

[image]

But i want to move my blue button  to top as this image shows below and change the background color to grey :

[image]

This my custom layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/Grey_300"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/Grey_50"
            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_video"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_overimage"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/myred"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_amazon_title"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_video"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageview_video"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_datetimevideo"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_video"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageview_video"
                    android:textColor="@color/Grey_500"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_amazon_title"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_deal"
                    android:text="Voir le deal"
                    android:backgroundTint="@drawable/back_amazon"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_datetimevideo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view_video"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/bt_deal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/favorite"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/view_video"
                    android:background="@drawable/favorite"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can i do that ? Should i create another linearLayout and add the button inside the linearlayout ?

My updated code and image after adding linearlayout inside cardview :

[image]

updated code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/Grey_300"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/Grey_50"
            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear2"
            android:background="@color/Grey_300"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rela1"
                android:background="@color/Grey_300"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_deal2"
                    android:text="Voir le deal"
                    android:backgroundTint="@drawable/back_amazon"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_video"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_overimage"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/myred"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_amazon_title"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_video"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageview_video"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_datetimevideo"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_video"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageview_video"
                    android:textColor="@color/Grey_500"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_amazon_title"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_deal"
                    android:text="I HIDE BUTTON FOR REMOVING AFTER"
                    android:backgroundTint="@drawable/back_amazon"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_datetimevideo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view_video"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/bt_deal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/favorite"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/view_video"
                    android:background="@drawable/favorite"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes , you have to create a linearlayout inside the cardview and design the button section (header section )with background grey

Comment: @AmruthaSaj i have updated the code and image please can you see check them i have added the linearlayout with button but how do i make the relative layout below the new linearlayout added

Comment: why do you want to add a relative layout inside your leanear layout? I think you may remove that and try .

Comment: @AmruthaSaj no i don t want to add i meant how do i re update the code because the linearlayout i haved added recently is overlapping image and textview

Comment: @AmruthaSaj Wow great it works perfectly !! Thanks a lot friend

Comment: oh great. i was not sure whether you get it or not. thats why i removed the comment.

Comment: also please update the answer. so that it may help someone.)Happy codding.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding both your linearlayouts inside a parent linearlayout with orientation vertical.